# (.text+0xb6f): undefined reference to `src_simple'

Tags: c

i am using libresample to resample a data. i have include samplerate.h in my C code but when i compile it there is an error displaying 
(.text+0xb6f): undefined reference to `src_simple' is there anyone with solution. thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're not *linking* against the library. (That is: the compilation itself is fine -- you can produce an `.o` file -- but linking the compiled object-files into a single executable is failing.) What command are you using to compile and link your program?

Comment: With the help of a google search, you could have at least refined your question, if not found an answer to your problem.

Comment: tnx ruakh i am trying to compile it invoking gcc myfile.c -o output

Answer (score 1):

According to [the gcc manual, "link options" section](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options), you should be able to link to lib*resample*, providing lib*resample*.a is present in whichever directory your system uses for libraries, by invoking `gcc your_file.c -lresample`.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply but i tried ur command still generating error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lresample

Comment: @Tmichael This is irrelevant to the question, but how did you build libresample? Where is the libresample library located?

Comment: i tried with -lsamplerate instead of -lresample then it works thanks i did it according to the hint u gave me!